# передать состояние нажатия на кнопку в объект массива и запретить нажатие на кнопку из коллекции react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть коллекция кнопок, и я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на определенную кнопку не нажималась аналогичная кнопка в других коллекциях.

Например:

```
<div>
 <button>A-1</button>
 <button>A-2</button>
 <button>A-3</button>
 <button>B-1</button>
 <button>B-2</button>
 <button>B-3</button>
</div>

<div>
 <button>A-1</button>
 <button>A-2</button>
 <button>A-3</button>
 <button>B-1</button>
 <button>B-2</button>
 <button>B-3</button>
</div>
```

И когда я нажимаю на кнопку `B-3`, я хочу, чтобы все кнопки `B-3`, кроме текущей, были как `disabled`.

Например, я щелкаю на кнопке `B-3`, и все `B-3` отключаются, кроме текущей.

На самом деле это легко сделать, но я хочу хранить состояние нажатой кнопки в хуке в ключе объекта массива. И передавать в хук состояние нажатых кнопок типа `B-*`:

```
const [Buttons, setButtons] = useState([{ ClickedButtons: [null, null] }]);

null #1 - `A-*` кнопки
null #2 - `B-*` кнопки
```

Немного не понимаю, как заносить состояние нажатой кнопки в этот хук, и отключать все аналогичные. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<ClickedButtons id={1} />
<ClickedButtons id={2} />
<ClickedButtons id={3} />

<ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={1} buttons={buttons} />
<ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={2} buttons={buttons} />
<ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={3} buttons={buttons} />
```

Comment: Кнопки в двух коллекциях это одни и те же или их состав может быть разным, но пересекаться по некоторму id?

Comment: Одни и те же кнопки

Comment: т.е. это даже будет конкретный компонент, содержащий кнопки, но вызван несколько раз просто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовать такое поведение можно, допустим, сохраняя в состояние кнопки ID "контейнера", где был произведен клик и при рендере проверять:

- Если клика нет `clickId === 0`, кнопка активна
- Если клик был, то проверяем, что клик был в текущем контейнере
- Если в текущем, кнопка активна иначе не активна

---

Создадим, к примеру, такую структуру для каждой кнопки:

```
{
    name: "A-1", // Название кнопки
    clickId: 0, // Где нажата
    buttonId: 1, // ID кнопки
},
```

Создадим компонент, который будет отвечать за рендер кнопок и их состояние

```
const ButtonShow = ({ buttons, id, clickFn }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {buttons.map((button) => (
        <button
          // По клику передаем Id кнопки и id контейнера
          onClick={() => clickFn(button.buttonId, id)}
          // Если заполнен клик и он не из этого контейнера, отключаем кнопку
          disabled={button.clickId && button.clickId !== id}
        >
          {button.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

В основном компоненте создаем состояние и функцию обработчик клика по кнопке

```
function App() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([...buttonsInit]);

  const btnClick = (btnId, rndId) => {
    setButtons((prev) => {
      return prev.map((btn) => {
        // Если ID кнопки не совпало, возвращаем элемент как есть
        if (btn.buttonId !== btnId) return btn;
        // Если ID контейнера совпадает, отключаем клик
        // Если нет, устанавливаем
        btn.clickId = rndId === btn.clickId ? 0 : rndId;
        return btn;
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={1} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={2} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={3} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Полный код:

```js
const buttonsInit = [
  {
    name: "A-1",
    clickId: 0,
    buttonId: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "A-2",
    clickId: 0,
    buttonId: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "B-1",
    clickId: 0,
    buttonId: 3,
  },
  {
    name: "B-2",
    clickId: 0,
    buttonId: 4,
  },
];

const ButtonShow = ({ buttons, id, clickFn }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {buttons.map((button) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => clickFn(button.buttonId, id)}
          disabled={button.clickId && button.clickId !== id}
        >
          {button.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([...buttonsInit]);

  const btnClick = (btnId, rndId) => {
    setButtons((prev) => {
      return prev.map((btn) => {
        if (btn.buttonId !== btnId) return btn;
        btn.clickId = rndId === btn.clickId ? 0 : rndId;
        return btn;
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={1} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={2} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
      <ButtonShow clickFn={btnClick} id={3} buttons={buttons} />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Рабочий пример в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-roentgen-vddp4f)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, это работает так, как нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу занести нажатые кнопки в  компонент `<ClickedButtons />` ? Т.е. три компонента с кнопками, и три компонента `<ClickedButtons />`, в котором я хочу просто отображать нажатые кнопки. Я обновил свой вопрос. В самом низу код.

Comment: @rabbit Создайте переменную состояния и туда добавляйте нажатые кнопки, а после отжатия, удаляйте из массива...

Answer (score 1):

> И когда я нажимаю на кнопку B-3, я хочу, чтобы все кнопки B-3, кроме текущей, были как disabled.

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [
  ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'B-1', 'B-2', 'B-3'],
  ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'B-1', 'B-2', 'B-3'],
]

//
function App() {
  const [slct, setSlct] = React.useState({})
  console.log(slct)
  return <section>
    {arr.map((a, i) => <Blk key={i} arr={a} line={i} set={setSlct} slct={slct} />)}
  </section>
}
//
function Blk({arr, line, set, slct}) {
  const act = e => {
    const o = e.target
    const ol = o.closest('.blk')
    const i = +ol.dataset.line
    const v = o.textContent
    set(old => {
      if (old[v] !== undefined) delete old[v]
      else old[v] = i
      return {...old}
    })
  }
  return <div className="blk" data-line={line}>
    {arr.map(v => <button className={cls(v)} onClick={act} key={v} disabled={dis(v)}>{v}</button>)}
  </div>
  //
  function cls(v) {
    if (slct[v] === line) return 'on'
    return null
  }
  //
  function dis(v) {
    if (slct[v] === undefined) return false
    if (slct[v] !== line) return true
    return false
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.blk {
  margin: 10px;
}
.on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!